# Rails - How many controllers required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm learning rails from scratch, and I've been studying it for a while but something is not clear to me.

I have to 'move' a Django-based website to a Rails-based. 
The website is very simple and consists of a mini 'social network', which has a structure like:

```
social/index
social/signup
social/login
social/profile
social/members
social/messages
social/logout
```

My question is: should I create **ONE** controller `SOCIAL` and make each page (i.e index, signup, login etc) functions of this controller; or should I generate one controller for each page (resulting in **SEVEN** controllers) ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd create one controller for each resource ;-)

Comment: You should always think in resources. I would say you have 3 resources here: `session`, `members` and `messages`. Now it is not certain for me what index page does in the original website or how are messages associated with members, however I am pretty certian that 3 controllers would be ok.

Comment: What do they do?  Looks like signup, profile and members would be new, show and index actions of a user controller respectively.  Then I'd have a sessions controller for login and logout, and another one for index where my app is routed to personally. Forgot messages.  I'm with @BroiSatse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `sessions_controller` for `login` and `logout`. Here, you need to add a session and remove a session - they are managed in the same controller.

Create a `users_controller` for `signup` and `members` (and possibly `profile`). Here, you want to create a new user, view all users, and view the information on a particular user.

Create a `messages_controller` for `messages`

Create a `main_controller` to manage your `index`/homepage.